# Encontrar valor máximo en un group by pero mostrar información almacenada en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, group-by

Estoy aprendiendo bbdd y me he encontrado con un problema que no sé resolver. Creo que es relativamente sencillo pero me estoy volviendo loco.

Tengo dos tablas: producto (id, nombre, precio, id_fabricante) y fabricante (id, nombre)

El código completo para la creación de la bbdd, las tablas y la insercción de los datos es el siguiente:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tienda;

CREATE DATABASE tienda CHARACTER SET utf8mb4; 

USE tienda;

CREATE TABLE fabricante (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,
id_fabricante INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_fabricante) REFERENCES fabricante(id)
);

INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard'); 
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte'); 
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5); 
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6); 
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7); 
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6); 
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1); 
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1); 
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

Me gustaría mostrar un listado con el nombre del producto más caro que tiene cada fabricante mostrando tres columnas: el nombre del fabricante, el precio del producto y el nombre del producto. Si no tuviese que mostrar el nombre del producto no habría problema (agrupando por fabricante.nombre y con la función max(precio)), mi duda me surge al tener que añadir ese dato.

¿Podéis echarme una mano?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar buscamos el mayor precio entre los productos de cada fabricante:

```
select id_fabricante, 
       max(precio) as precio
       from producto
       group by id_fabricante
```

Teniendo el fabricante y el precio máximo de sus productos, podemos usarlo en una subconsulta para obtener el producto en sí:

```
select f.id,
       f.nombre,
       p.id,
       p.nombre,
       p.precio
       from producto p
       inner join (
             select id_fabricante, max(precio) as precio
                    from producto
                    group by id_fabricante
             ) m
             ON p.id_fabricante = m.id_fabricante
             and p.precio = m.precio
      inner join fabricante f
            on f.id = p.id_fabricante
      order by f.id;
```

Aclaración: Si un fabricante tiene más de un producto con el mismo precio máximo, esta consulta recuperará todos estos.

Consultar ejemplo en [`fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/2OR1nxGg)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio por tu respuesta. Me ha funcionado correctamente. Gracias de nuevo.